# Can't open files generated by PHP app on windows

Tags: php, windows, file-upload, permissions

I'm having a problem when I try to open files that were generated by my CMS on my windows machine. It has an upload function that saves the file on a given location (it is on my user folder, where I'm supposed to have all the write and read permissions).

All I can see in that folder is a generic thumbnail, the ones generated by windows for each image type, PNGs and JPEGs in this case. I tried to change de image permissions and set it to the current computer user but it doesn't work. And I'm unable to move these files to another location (upload them to the server via FTP).

I wonder if there is a way to change this behavior.

One thing I noticed is that if I copy and paste those files, I can see its contents normally. I know I can do that to each of them and rename, but there are dozens of images in that folder... don't wanna do the same thing everytime I upload a new image.

**Update**

This is happening only to the images that were moved (I'm using php's [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function, btw), not to the ones that where generated (croped, resized and so on).

Comment: What are the filenames like? How are you trying to open them? What CMS?

Comment: The filenames have no special chars, for example "somefile.png". I'm trying to open them with an ordinary double click and the CMS I'm programming myself using Laravel.

Comment: when you say on windows..., does it work on anything else?

Comment: @DanyKhalife hm... not that I'm aware of. I've mentioned "Windows" just to reference the OS I'm using right now.

Comment: oh ok i see, well in that case i explained below how you could debug the code

Answer (score 1):

It`s happening because Windows keep file permissions of TEMP folder (usually c:/windows/temp) when moving a file. 
To prevent it you need to change "upload_tmp_dir" in "php.ini" to your server directory or set wide permissions to your windows temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error in some php file which is preventing the image from being displayed correctly.

What i would do in order to detect the problem is to comment out the `header()` calls in the php file responsible for displaying the image and see if there is any output other than the image data.

Inspect the whole output, it only takes a character to break everything, so check if there are no blank lines at the top or bottom of the output. And in case you have an error log, consult that, it will help you trace the problem quickly.

When i have this problem, it's usually a notice or a warning showing up during the process of the image generation, and if you haven't disabled errors from being output to the screen, the notice text will be considered as part of the image data which makes the browser unable to interpret your image.

If you'd like i can take a look closely for you but i would need to see what you are doing in that php file to be able to tell you for sure.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't as clear as I meant to. I have no issues on displaying the images in the browser; They are showing up as expected. The problem is that I can't see the images in the Windows filesystem. But not being able to see them isn't the problem at all... the real thing is that I can't upload the files to the server via a ftp program (like Filezilla, for example) because I always got an "access denied" error from the FTP program.